# not recognizing select option if user selects other inputfield

Tags: yii

If I don't have an option to select an input field, the form saves the selection. But when I add a selection where user can select for an input field, the entire selection option is not recognized.

I am getting 'dropdown_column cannot be blank'

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'dropdown_column'); ?>
<p><?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'dropdown_column',
    array('Option 1', 
    'Option 2',  
    'Option 3', 
    'Option 4',  
    'Other' //<--input field if selected
    ),array('class'=>'span4','name'=>'dropdown')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'dropdown_column'); ?>
    <div id="pre-input">
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'dropdown_column',array('class'=>'span4','maxlength'=>45,'placeholder'=>'Something')); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem, but it sounds like you could solve it using `'empty'` and `'prompt'` options for your dropDownList.

```
$form->dropDownList($model,'dropdown_column',
    array(....), //name value pair as options
    array(
        'class'=>'span4',
        'name'=>'dropdown',
        'prompt' => 'value_for_propmt',
        'empty' =>'value_when_empty'
    )
);
```

More info [on the official Yii docs for dropDownList() method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail).

Hope this helps

Comment: this is not what im looking for. I have an option that allows user to input something. So a js is called to show that input field if a selection is made, however, the form never recognize the selection.